# I can't delete a folder that I just extracted from a zip file in python

Tags: python, windows, windows-vista, operating-system, zip

So here's my problem. I have a python script that takes a zipfile and extracts its contents. Then based on some constraint, I will try to delete the folder whose contents were just extracted. For some reason I get an error, WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'Foldername' when i try to delete that folder. The simple code looks like the following

wzip = zipfile.ZipFile('zipfile.zip')

wzip.extractall()

wzip.close()

os.remove('ExtractedFolder')

If I run this in the interpreter I get the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'ExtractedFolder'

I'm using Python 2.6 on Windows Vista 32-bit and I'm kinda baffled as to why this might be happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many reasons possible.

1. You need to use `os.rmdir` to remove directories
2. You need to empty the folder
   first - remember, the Windows command
   `rmdir` needs a `/S` option to
   remove the contents, and Python probably uses that.
3. Is the unzip
   also using the archive's attributes?
   Read-only attributes may be applied.
4. Are you reading anything from that
   folder, before you delete? You may
   not have closed it.
5. Windows can cause similar problems with filenames containing
   unusual characters

Comment: I believe you're right on 1. and 2. os.remove was the wrong command and os.rmdir would have worked as well except for the fact that the folder is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

I see a possible problem on Windows, which is that you could have an opened file in this directory. Make sure that you close explicitly all the files that you have opened using `file.close()` (your sample code looks right, though).

Also, it might be useful to have a look at `shutils.rmtree`: it can recursively remove directories, and capture errors.

Comment: Thanks. since the folder wasn't empty, I was supposed to use shutil.rmtree